# Is it possible to turn off bluetooth when the battery level is below 40%?

Tags: android, power-management

Is it possible to turn off bluetooth when the battery level is below 40% ? I am developing an application, which turns off bluetooth and wifi automatically when the battery level is below 41%. Can i do this programatically in Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but i think you can you have to use `BroadcastListener` in your application which is mostly used for listening short events when ever any event is occured on android OS level android OS BroadCast that event after that you can perform any task i.e if you want to turn off your bluetooth you can.

Answer (score 3):

you can get the level of the battery from the follwoing code:

```
private void batteryLevel() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                batterLevel.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    }
```

and then use this level to switch off the bluetooth using the follwing code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() && level < 40) 
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
    }
```

you can get more info on the following link for battery info:
http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [link](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html). It contains the code of checking battery level through programming.

You only need to modify the code as , when it is 40% just switch off the Bluetooth